# Flatten Arrays While Retaining Keys

Tags: php, arrays

How can I flatten an array while retaining its keys?

Say for example I have the following array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'bonus' => float 20
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'bonus_percent' => float 2
      array (size=1)
         'bonus_all' => float 22
```

How can I "flatten" it to be like this? :

```
array (size=2)
  'bonus' => float 20
  'bonus_percent' => float 2
  'bonus_all' => float 22
```

I have found this function from SO also, which results to the current results.

```
$objTmp = (object) array('aFlat' => array());

array_walk_recursive($results, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->aFlat[] = $v;'), $objTmp);

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

If there are no deeper levels you need to flatten, a loop is probably an easier solution than using `array_walk_recursive()`.

Something like:

```
$original = array(...);
$result = array();

foreach ($original as $value) {
    $result += $value;
}
```